# Can't push to View Controller from AppDelegate without losing Navigation Bar and Tab Bar setup iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I try to push to specific view controller from app delegate without losing previously set navigation bar and tab bar items setup.

As presented in my Main storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

After 1 action performed in TypeNameVC, on app relaunch I want to skip LogInVC and TypeNameVC in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate forward to MapViewController or any other VC of Tab Bar Controller.

This code initializes new Navigation Controller with new Navigation Bar and Tab Bar Controller is missing.

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
//To instantiate Main.storyboard.
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
//To instantiate VC to go to.
MapViewController *mapVC = (MapViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewControllerID"];
//To push to instantiated VC.
[navigationController pushViewController:mapVC animated:YES];
```

I tried to `performSegue` using segue to Tab Bar Controller but on Navigation Controller stack there is only LoginViewController (I checked it with `[navigationController viewControllers]`)

I read through entire Stack Overflow, I made dozens of combinations but I can't figure out the solution. I would appreciate any help/advice.

**UPDATED QUESTION**
Screen: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZOGf.png)

Have a look to the screen image. First row of screen shows how it looks like if I navigate "normally". Second row shows what happens if I push to MapVC from AppDelegate. What I need is to skip first two VC's with maintaining Navigation and Tab Bar bars setup.

When I navigate "normally" Tab Bar Controller and it's VC's get correctly allocated.

2016-06-08 12:37:44.394 Checkpoint[4196:1034786] Navigation Controller VC's: (
    LogInViewController: 0x135d50b00,
    TypeNameViewController: 0x135f455b0,
    UITabBarController: 0x135f1d180
)
2016-06-08 12:37:44.394 Checkpoint[4196:1034786] Tab Bar Controller VC's: (
    MapViewController: 0x137078cf0,
    PlacesTableViewController: 0x135f1d7d0,
    FriendsTableViewController: 0x137083350
)

When I push directly to MapVC they don't. I do get the point what's going on but I know how to code that solution.

Navigation Controller VC's:   (
    LogInViewController: 0x15fd5ccf0,
    MapViewController: 0x15fd6ffa0
)
2016-06-08 12:31:53.813 Checkpoint[4187:1033755] Tab Bar Controller VC's: (null)

Answer (score 0):

Customize your class MapViewController for visible **Navigation Bar** and **Tab Bar**:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    // init code        
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
    retur self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // some code
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for helping. I tried your solution but nothing has changed compared to solution I already have. Please have a look to my updated question for more details.

Comment: Hi! I think you create wrong hierarchy. Make 2 different storyboard(Auth and Main, for example). Also, **UITabBarController** should be root vc, and contain **navigation controller** for each tab( 3 navigation vc, in your case). It should work ;D

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice, I rearranged everything and it worked.